# launch error code 8 to build python or python3 on xcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode

I'm new to python and want to study it on xcode. I followed some method from internet but when I test 
`print('hello')`

Build success message appears with no result and mini window `'Launch error There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 8).' details : Code: 9  Recovery Suggestion: There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 8)` -> [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVsjy.png)

Here's what I did to launch python. 
new xcode project other-external build system-build tool:usr/bin/python3 - new file-empty-save as: python3.py, targeting: testing(project name)- edit scheme-info-executable:Python3 , uncheck debug executable-arguments-arguments passed on launch: python3.py  ,expand variables based on:testing-options-working directory:custom  /testing (path I saved the project) -print('hello') -run-error

What should I do? I downloaded python3 and tried both python and python3 to build, same error. IDLE Shell 3.9.1 works well

xcode version is 12.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error you described, and I tried to update Python with HomeBrew, which was successfully done.
I am almost arriving to the conclusion that Xcode12 is not compatible with Python3.
Maybe a illuminated soul could help us.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Solved the same problem by changing the path to python.

Project settings>Info>External Build Tool Configuration>Build Tool = /usr/bin/python3

https://imgur.com/a/aOp1w8a